# How can i print the values in key-value pair in python

Tags: python

```
class_roll = {'amit':1,'suresh:':2,'mahesh':23,'rajesh':13,'chandrashekar':21}
print(class_roll)
print('the roll no of amit is:{0}'.format(class_roll('amit')) )
```

After compiling i got a error saying,

```
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Comment: To access dict elements use `[]`, not `()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly change the code and get the expected result.

```
class_roll = {'amit':1,'suresh:':2,'mahesh':23,'rajesh':13,'chandrashekar':21}
print(class_roll)
print('the roll no of amit is:{0}'.format(class_roll['amit']) )
```

output is

```
{'amit': 1, 'suresh:': 2, 'mahesh': 23, 'rajesh': 13, 'chandrashekar': 21}
the roll no of amit is:1
```